# Can the lifetime of a broken covalent bond be calculated?

Tags: thermodynamics, solid-state-physics, molecular-dynamics, quasiprobability-distributions

According to a paper (molecular dynamic simulation) published in 2018,(https://www.scirp.org/journal/paperinformation.aspx?paperid=83351) the Maxwell-Boltzman distribution is also valid for the number distribution of atoms having different energy in a solid at a particular temperature.
Thus if we know the covalent bond energy then the number of broken bonds in a solid at a particular temperature can be calculated by Maxwell-Boltzman distribution. In any instant of time some bonds will break and some will be reinstated and a dynamical equilibrium will be established.

For example, the melting point of $Ga_2O_3$ is 1900C. The bond energy of Ga-O covalent bond is 285kJ/mole. Suppose we want to calculate the number of broken Ga-O bonds at its melting point or little less temperature than melting point. Then we can use the Maxwell Boltzman equation to calculate it.

Can we calculated the lifetime of a broken Ga-O bond (how much time it remains broken) by knowing the bond energy and temperature of a $Ga_2O_3$ crystal?

Comment: Yes, it can be calculated. But I suggest that you formulate more specific questions.

Comment: I have modified the question by giving an example. Please go through it.

Comment: You two are overlooking the fact that the potential they use isn't valid for any chemically hold solid or entity (molecule, ionic solid, covalent solid, molecular solid). It is not a coincidence that they use Ar-like particles.

Comment: Adding to the above, one can easily take the band structure and compute the number of electrons in excited states. But are those 'broken bonds'? Similarly one can calculate the density of interstitials and vacancies from their formation energies which have little to do with your computed bond energies. Solid crystals are not molecules and can't be treated the same way.